# GitLab CI Error: Uploading artifacts to coordinator - failed - responseStatus 400 Bad Request

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

I'm working with GitLab (free edition) pipelines and started receiving the error below on **a pipeline that was working**.

This is a minimal example from my `.gitlab-ci.yml` that reproduce the error (Although I don't think it is related to my code):

```
default:
  image: node:10-alpine

stages:
- build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - npm install
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - node_modules/
  only:
  - Staging
.
.
.
```

Error's log:

```
 64 packages are looking for funding
   run `npm fund` for details
Running after_script
Saving cache
Uploading artifacts for successful job
 Uploading artifacts...
 node_modules/: found 62788 matching files          
 WARNING: Uploading artifacts to coordinator... failed  id=512111 responseStatus=400 Bad Request status=400 Bad Request token=4Dwaaa
 WARNING: Retrying...                                context=artifacts-uploader error=invalid argument
 WARNING: Uploading artifacts to coordinator... failed  id=512111 responseStatus=400 Bad Request status=400 Bad Request token=4Dwaaa
 WARNING: Retrying...                                context=artifacts-uploader error=invalid argument
 WARNING: Uploading artifacts to coordinator... failed  id=512111 responseStatus=400 Bad Request status=400 Bad Request token=4Dwaaa
 FATAL: invalid argument                            
 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47363520/error-uploading-artifacts-to-coordinator) thread in Stackoverfow but it is related to different status error.

There are multiple threads ([1](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/freedesktop/freedesktop/issues/44) , [2](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab/issues/1652) , [3](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab/issues/1651) ) on this issue on Gitlab forum but it is hard to understand the cause of the problem and how to resolve it.

Any help will be highly appriciated.

Comment: About week after - It seems that the guys on GitLab fixed the issue - the pipeline came back to life.

Comment: Which GitLab server and runner versions did you use when this happened? We have a similar problem on GitLab Community Edition 12.9.2 and GitLab Runner 13.3.1.

Comment: Same here for GitLab CE 13.4.1 and Runner 13.4.1. Here is an issue at Gitlab's tracker that seems to be more relevant: [link](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/212629)

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is probably becasue of your backend storage is ceph based ,
you have to follow below on your gitlab cli to solve your 4xx error :

```bash
bash:~$ gitlab-rails console
irb(main): > Feature.disable(:s3_multithreaded_uploads)
#making sure feature is disabled -->
irb(main): > Feature.disabled?(:s3_multithreaded_uploads)
true
```